# Unused parser rule is causing an error, depending on the definition - WHY?

Tags: java, antlr

I got an error that I don't understand and it's about the "testRule" below.

```
grammar MyTest;

myTest: line+ EOF;

testRule: '\n\n' ; //this produces an error - WHY?
//testRule: '\n\n\n\n' ; //no error
//testRule: Break Break ; //no error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are indirectly declaring a lexer rule matching `\n\n` by using `'\n\n'` in a parser rule.

This "new" lexer rule is specified before all other lexer rules (as they are specified after the `'...'`-construct in the source code) which causes it to be consulted first.

Therefore the input `\n\n` will not produce two `Break`-tokens but one single token corresponding to the indirectly specified lexer rule.

As the parser does only care about token-type and not about it's content it will tell you that it doesn't know what to do with it (as it was expecting one or two `Break` tokens but got one "other" token). Thus it complains.

This is the reason why you should **never** use those indirect lexer rule specifications outside of really small (testing-) grammars. Always create a separate lexer rule so you will always see what token-types there are going to be in your grammar.